# How to remove all excess space and newlines in Excel with formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have one large excel file with cells having big strings. Some cells have huge text with multiple newlines and more than one consecutive white spaces.

Can anyone help me with any formula that will **replace** all the excess space and new lines with single whitespace.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Remove-spaces-and-nonprinting-characters-from-text-023f3a08-3d56-49e4-bf0c-fe5303222c9d

Comment: I've tried `=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(32)," "))` but it doesn't replace new line or line break. It only replace consecutive spaces with single space.

Comment: try use the CLEAN() function. it removes linebreak

Comment: To replace multiple, consecutive white spaces you'll need to use a vba function.

Comment: @MikeC I tried to replace the line breaks with spaces. Replace --> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> with ` `(whitespace). This actually replace line breaks with whitespace in Excel but in the original CSV file it still exist.

Comment: If you had opened the CSV file in Excel, you can save the Excel file back into the CSV file.